# Java sort Arraylist and return sorted list

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Hello am trying to return a sorted Arraylist by date property  like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784576/2506749)

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {
@Override
public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
    return o1.getStartDate().compareTo(o2.getStartDate());
}
}
```

My question is how can i return a sorted list instead of returning an int... 
**What i need is just a method i pass it my list then it returns a sorted list.**

In my case i have many items in list, i dont know whether it's possible to compare all items and sort them accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Collections.sort(yourList, new CustomComparator())

Comment: hi @Eran can you please post some example, thanks

Comment: So you read the answer, but haven't looked once at the question? It shows you how to use this `CustomComparator`.

Comment: @C.B my comment contains all the code you'll need (beside the CustomComparator class which you already have)

Comment: The method `compare` is used to compare two objects for the already aviable sorting. It has to be overriden to be able to implement a custom sorting (like you are trying). You simply need to call `list.sort(new CustomCoperator())`

Comment: @KevinEsche how to compare all items in list then return sorted list

Comment: @Tom apologies am just looking for an answer, i did't get the other answer that's why i had to ask. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want the sorted `List` to be separated from the original one, do it like this.

```
/**
 * @param input The unsorted list
 * @return a new List with the sorted elements
 */
public static List<Integer> returnSortedList(List<Integer> input) {
    List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(input);
    sortedList.sort(new CustomComparator());
    return sortedList;
}
```

If you also want to change the original `List`, simply invoke it on the original instance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(0); 
    list.add(1);
    list.add(23);
    list.add(50);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(20);
    list.add(17);

    list.sort(new CustomComparator());
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do like this.

```
List<MyClass> unsortedList=...
List<MyClass> sortedList = unsortedList.stream()
            .sorted((MyClass o1, MyClass o2) -> o1.getStartDate().compareTo(o2.getStartDate()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**A more short form can be**

```
List<MyClass> sortedList = unsortedList.stream()
                .sorted((o1,o2) -> o1.getStartDate().compareTo(o2.getStartDate()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

After implementing Comaparator interface you have to call

```
      // sort the list
      Collections.sort(list);
```

method to sort the list.
See Example [here](http://java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/arraylist/sort-comparator/) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_sort_comparable.htm).

Comment: This doesn't return a sorted list. `Collections.sort(List<T>)` sorts the supplied list in-place.